# How do I check if a surface is sloping?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm implementing gravity over a 3D terrain and I'm struggling with how to check if surface "under your feet" is flat or sloping.

I read some tutorials but gravity is always considered along a single axis.

How do I proceed?

Comment: If your surface is triangulated, you can always compute the normal vector which is pointing upwards, towards the sky. You can then take the magnitude of its z (or whichever axis is up for you) component and use it as a slope measure with 0 being perfectly vertical and 1 being perfectly flat/horizontal.

Comment: my surface is triangulated, indeed. This sounds to me like a very good starting point. Could you please  post it like an answer so I could accept it? Since I'm quite a beginner would you also please elaborate the concept making (or linking to) a concrete example so I could understand better what does mean to take the magnitude? Thank you

Comment: thank you Anko! it's a long way to the top if you wanna learn proper english :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just calculate the [dot-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of your "up-vector" and the normal of the surface below your feet.

So assume you have a world where positive-Y is up, then your up-vector is `(0,1,0)`. Then get the normal of the triangle below your feet and calculate the dot-product.

```
float dot = Vector3.Dot(upVector, normalVector);
```

The dot product will be the cosine of the angle of these two normal vectors. It will be `1.0` when both normals point in the same direction (eg. your plane is absolutely flat), `0.0` when the normals are perpendicular and `-1.0` when they are pointing in the opposite direction.

Your check if a surface is sloping could be a simple threshold comparison, such as:

```
// 0.8f is just some arbitrary value.. could be 0.9f or even higher
// if you want to make sure the surface is as close to flat as possible
bool isSlope = Vector3.Dot(upVector, normalVector) < 0.8f;
```

Some other thing to consider is the coarseness of your mesh. If you have really small triangles (compared to the "feet" of your character), you might get unwanted results if you just consider a single triangle and its normal. Instead you might want to average the normals of several triangles and use that for your calculation.

Comment: This explaination is exactly what I was searching for. Thank you bummzack!

Comment: Make sure that both vectors are normalized.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah you're right, that *is* important. I assumed this is the case though. The Up-Vector can be created manually and the mesh normals are usually normalized.